# Latitude, Longitutde and SVG's

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, coordinates

I am trying to represent an airport and its airspace using an SVG. I have triple checked the coordinates and it still looks like something is wrong with y-axis and how they are converted. When you load the code below line representing runway 09L / 27R should be above 09R / 27L and LON should be above the both lines. Is there some magic trick to doing this using svg or my logic is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Radar Screen</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrolling */
    }

    #radar-container {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    svg {
      width: 100%; /* Take full width of container */
      height: 100%; /* Take full height of container */
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="radar-container">
    <svg id="radar-svg">
      <!-- Runways, waypoints, and airport will be dynamically drawn here -->
    </svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Function to convert latitude and longitude to screen coordinates
    function convertCoordinates(latitude, longitude) {
        // Airport coordinates
        const airportLatitude = 51.4775; // Decimal degrees
        const airportLongitude = -0.46139; // Decimal degrees

        // Calculate center of SVG based on airport coordinates
        const centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        const centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        // Assume some mapping between latitude and y-axis, and longitude and x-axis
        // You may need to adjust these calculations based on your specific mapping
        const scaleFactor = 2000; // Adjust based on the scale of your radar screen
        const offsetX = centerX - (airportLongitude * scaleFactor);
        const offsetY = centerY - (airportLatitude * scaleFactor);
        const screenX = (longitude * scaleFactor) + offsetX;
        const screenY = (latitude * scaleFactor) + offsetY;
        return { x: screenX, y: screenY };
    }

    // Waypoint coordinates
    const waypointCoordinates = [
      { name: "LON", latitude: 51.4861, longitude: -0.4666 },
    ];

    // Runway coordinates
    const runwayCoordinates = [
      { id: "27R", start: { latitude: 51.4776, longitude: -0.4332 }, end: { latitude: 51.4775, longitude: -0.4849 }},
      { id: "09L", start: { latitude: 51.4775, longitude: -0.4849 }, end: { latitude: 51.4776, longitude: -0.4332 }},
      { id: "09R", start: { latitude: 51.4647, longitude: -0.4823 }, end: { latitude: 51.4655, longitude: -0.4341 }},
      { id: "27L", start: { latitude: 51.4655, longitude: -0.4341 }, end: { latitude: 51.4647, longitude: -0.4823 }}
    ];

    // Get the SVG container
    const svgContainer = document.getElementById('radar-svg');

    // Function to draw waypoints
    function drawWaypoints() {
      // Draw new waypoints
      waypointCoordinates.forEach(waypoint => {
        const position = convertCoordinates(waypoint.latitude, waypoint.longitude);

        console.log(`Waypoint ${waypoint.name} position: (${position.x}, ${position.y})`);

        // Draw square representing waypoint
        const square = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
        square.setAttribute('x', position.x - 5); // Adjust position to center square
        square.setAttribute('y', position.y - 5); // Adjust position to center square
        square.setAttribute('width', 10);
        square.setAttribute('height', 10);
        square.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
        svgContainer.appendChild(square);

        // Add label for the waypoint
        const label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        label.setAttribute('x', position.x + 10); // Offset label position
        label.setAttribute('y', position.y - 10); // Offset label position
        label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start'); // Align text to start of label
        label.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', 'middle'); // Center the text vertically
        label.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
        label.setAttribute('font-size', '12');
        label.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
        label.textContent = waypoint.name;
        svgContainer.appendChild(label);
      });
    }

    // Function to draw runways
    function drawRunways() {
      // Draw new runways
      runwayCoordinates.forEach(runway => {
        const start = convertCoordinates(runway.start.latitude, runway.start.longitude);
        const end = convertCoordinates(runway.end.latitude, runway.end.longitude);

        console.log(`Runway ${runway.id} start: (${start.x}, ${start.y})`);
        console.log(`Runway ${runway.id} end: (${end.x}, ${end.y})`);

        const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        line.setAttribute('x1', start.x);
        line.setAttribute('y1', start.y);
        line.setAttribute('x2', end.x);
        line.setAttribute('y2', end.y);
        line.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
        line.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
        svgContainer.appendChild(line);
        // Add label
        const label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        label.setAttribute('x', start.x + 10); // Offset label position
        label.setAttribute('y', start.y - 10); // Offset label position
        label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start'); // Align text to start of label
        label.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', 'middle'); // Center the text vertically
        label.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
        label.setAttribute('font-size', '12');
        label.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
        label.textContent = runway.id;
        svgContainer.appendChild(label);
      });
    }

    // Draw waypoints and runways initially
    drawWaypoints();
    drawRunways();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried inverting the Y axis by doing:
`const screenY = -(latitude * scaleFactor) + offsetY;`

I have tripled checked coordinates too.

Comment: `return { x: screenX, y: window.innerHeight-screenY };` seems to do it

Answer (score 0):

I added four new points to your `waypointCoordinates` object, namely: NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, and WEST.

With this change you can see clearly see that the NORTH location is below LON and SOUTH is above LON.

One solution is indeed to change the object returned from `convertCoordinates()` to
`return { x: screenX, y: window.innerHeight - screenY };` as mentioned by Jaromanda in the comments to your question.

The issue here is that with longitude and latitude, the latitude origin is at the equator (i.e. `0`) and increases as we move north. However, the origin for SVG is the top left and increases as we move down. For this reason, we need to apply a negative sign to `screenY` in the above returned object and adjust the vertical screen position by adding `window.innerHeight`.

To make this easier to see, I added a flip checkbox in the top left which sits above the container thanks to adding `z-index: -1` to the `radar-container` `div`.

```js
const flipCheckbox = document.getElementById("flipCheckbox");

flipCheckbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
  while (svgContainer.lastChild) {
    svgContainer.removeChild(svgContainer.lastChild);
  }
  drawWaypoints();
  drawRunways();
});

// Function to convert latitude and longitude to screen coordinates
function convertCoordinates(latitude, longitude) {
  // Airport coordinates
  const airportLatitude = 51.4775; // Decimal degrees
  const airportLongitude = -0.46139; // Decimal degrees

  // Calculate center of SVG based on airport coordinates
  const centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  const centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  // Assume some mapping between latitude and y-axis, and longitude and x-axis
  // You may need to adjust these calculations based on your specific mapping
  const scaleFactor = 2000; // Adjust based on the scale of your radar screen
  const offsetX = centerX - (airportLongitude * scaleFactor);
  const offsetY = centerY - (airportLatitude * scaleFactor);
  const screenX = (longitude * scaleFactor) + offsetX;
  const screenY = (latitude * scaleFactor) + offsetY;
  return flipCheckbox.checked ? {
    x: screenX,
    y: window.innerHeight - screenY
  } : {
    x: screenX,
    y: screenY
  };
}

// Waypoint coordinates
const waypointCoordinates = [{
    name: "LON",
    latitude: 51.4861,
    longitude: -0.4666
  },
  {
    name: "EAST",
    latitude: 51.4861,
    longitude: -0.3375
  },
  {
    name: "NORTH",
    latitude: 51.5133,
    longitude: -0.4666
  },
  {
    name: "SOUTH",
    latitude: 51.4123,
    longitude: -0.4666
  },
  {
    name: "WEST",
    latitude: 51.4861,
    longitude: -0.5479
  }
];

// Runway coordinates
const runwayCoordinates = [{
    id: "27R",
    start: {
      latitude: 51.4776,
      longitude: -0.4332
    },
    end: {
      latitude: 51.4775,
      longitude: -0.4849
    }
  },
  {
    id: "09L",
    start: {
      latitude: 51.4775,
      longitude: -0.4849
    },
    end: {
      latitude: 51.4776,
      longitude: -0.4332
    }
  },
  {
    id: "09R",
    start: {
      latitude: 51.4647,
      longitude: -0.4823
    },
    end: {
      latitude: 51.4655,
      longitude: -0.4341
    }
  },
  {
    id: "27L",
    start: {
      latitude: 51.4655,
      longitude: -0.4341
    },
    end: {
      latitude: 51.4647,
      longitude: -0.4823
    }
  }
];

// Get the SVG container
const svgContainer = document.getElementById('radar-svg');

// Function to draw waypoints
function drawWaypoints() {
  // Draw new waypoints
  waypointCoordinates.forEach(waypoint => {
    const position = convertCoordinates(waypoint.latitude, waypoint.longitude);

    console.log(`Waypoint ${waypoint.name} position: (${position.x}, ${position.y})`);

    // Draw square representing waypoint
    const square = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
    square.setAttribute('x', position.x - 5); // Adjust position to center square
    square.setAttribute('y', position.y - 5); // Adjust position to center square
    square.setAttribute('width', 10);
    square.setAttribute('height', 10);
    square.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
    svgContainer.appendChild(square);

    // Add label for the waypoint
    const label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    label.setAttribute('x', position.x + 10); // Offset label position
    label.setAttribute('y', position.y - 10); // Offset label position
    label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start'); // Align text to start of label
    label.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', 'middle'); // Center the text vertically
    label.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
    label.setAttribute('font-size', '12');
    label.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
    label.textContent = waypoint.name;
    svgContainer.appendChild(label);
  });
}

// Function to draw runways
function drawRunways() {
  // Draw new runways
  runwayCoordinates.forEach(runway => {
    const start = convertCoordinates(runway.start.latitude, runway.start.longitude);
    const end = convertCoordinates(runway.end.latitude, runway.end.longitude);

    console.log(`Runway ${runway.id} start: (${start.x}, ${start.y})`);
    console.log(`Runway ${runway.id} end: (${end.x}, ${end.y})`);

    const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line.setAttribute('x1', start.x);
    line.setAttribute('y1', start.y);
    line.setAttribute('x2', end.x);
    line.setAttribute('y2', end.y);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2');
    svgContainer.appendChild(line);
    // Add label
    const label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    label.setAttribute('x', start.x + 10); // Offset label position
    label.setAttribute('y', start.y - 10); // Offset label position
    label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start'); // Align text to start of label
    label.setAttribute('dominant-baseline', 'middle'); // Center the text vertically
    label.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
    label.setAttribute('font-size', '12');
    label.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
    label.textContent = runway.id;
    svgContainer.appendChild(label);
  });
}

// Draw waypoints and runways initially
drawWaypoints();
drawRunways();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Prevent scrolling */
}

#radar-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  /* Take full width of container */
  height: 100%;
  /* Take full height of container */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
Flip Coordinates: <input type="checkbox" id="flipCheckbox">
<div id="radar-container">
  <svg id="radar-svg">
      <!-- Runways, waypoints, and airport will be dynamically drawn here -->
  </svg>
</div>
```